# Warm weather walkies and water

Tags: dogs, health

With the warmer weather, the 'walkies duty' hasn't lifted. When going out for longer walks on hot days, I've been taking with me a bottle of water and a bowl.

But I thought I'd ask - what's your 'rule of thumb' of how far you're going before you'd consider taking a dog drink with you? I've tended to assume up to about an hour walking, and 30m running/playing. Is this too long? (On a warm day)

And are there any better solutions to taking a backpack with water and a (fold up) bowl with us?

Comment: Where do you walk? Natural water-sources like lakes and streams come to mind, but also the shopkeeper of the cafe where you take a break, who will put out a bowl of water for your dog.

Comment: It varies a bit. Usually I'm not too far from a stream - although quite a few near us are more 'mucky mud holes' than 'flowing water'. But for longer walks, that's not so reliable - what streams there are might well not be accessible due to steep banks/undergrowth etc.

Comment: I think it really depends on the dog. I have a Bearded Collie (long, shaggy coat) who can easily walk for an hour in the hot weather without showing any effort. However, my six month old Golden Retriever puppy seems to be overheated after just 20 minutes in the heat. I carry water for the Golden, and the Beardie refuses it if I offer her some unless we have been walking for well over an hour.

Answer (score 3):

We usually do as you've said a backpack with water and a collapsible bowl, however there are usually plenty of places to get water for nothing.

We take our guy on 30-60 minute walks on occasion as he's still young and he is a long haired breed, however if we know our route will take us to rivers, lakes, streams etc, we won't always take water, but allow him plenty of time to stop and drink by the water. A bonus is many shops and pubs around us have dog water bowls outside, and one lovely house has one as well for passing walkers to allow their dog to drink!

I suppose it depends on how much you want to carry, but if you can't guarantee a source on route a bottle would be necessary, as a hiker I don't notice the extra weight much. You could invest in a bottle with the bowl attached that hook via a carabiner, but these are prone to leaking.

Another point to make is if you can't keep your hand on the floor (tarmac, sand, bare earth) for a good few seconds in hot weather, don't force your dog to walk on it.

I believe it better to take it and not need it, than leave it behind and find yourself wanting.

Comment: re: "bottle with a bowl attached" , the http://www.amazon.com/Gulpy-Water-Dispenser-20-Ounce-Colors/dp/B000TG7YRM Gulpy gets great reviews, haven't heard of one leaking.

Comment: @rlb.usa ahh the UK versions sold by most pets at home are reported to leak. I don't know if we have gulpy in the UK, we use a three peaks collapsible bowl and a thermos :) the bowl is handy for feeding lunch / dinner when out too